# Using MVC3 and EF4, how can one adequately test functionality that relies on a round trip to the database to create IDENTITY values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, entity-framework-4, moq

I have a scenario where the code under test inserts a record into a database, then attempts to retrieve it back from the database using its primary key.

This happens over a series of records in the same method.

I am mocking my ObjectContext and ObjectSets, so the current result is that each record "inserted" into my FakeObjectSet is given a primary key of 0.

In the case where I am only inserting a single record and asserting the record exists, this is fine...but when I am inserting multiple and my workflow requires retrieving specific records by primary key, my queries return multiple results since all inserts have a primary key of 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event to your `FakeObjectSet<T>` that will be raised when `AddObject` is called.  Then in your test, add an event handler to set the `Id` of the object being added.

For example, a simplified version of a fake object set:

```
public class ObjectAddedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}

public class FakeObjectSet<T>
{
    private List<T> _list = new List<T>();

    public event EventHandler<ObjectAddedEventArgs<T>> ObjectAdded;

    public void AddObject(T item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
        OnObjectAdded(item);
    }

    protected virtual void OnObjectAdded(T item)
    {
        EventHandler<ObjectAddedEventArgs<T>> h = AddingItem;
        if (h != null)
        {
            h(this, new ObjectAddedEventArgs<T> { Item = item });
        }
    }

    // other methods...
}
```

And in your test, when you want to set an incrementing `Id` value, add a handler to your `FakeObjectSet<T>` and update the object's `Id`:

```
int id = 0;

FakeObjectSet<Foo> set = new FakeObjectSet<Foo>();
set.ObjectAdded += (s, e) => { e.Item.Id = id++; };
```

Comment: This is by far the most thoughtful approach to the problem and I think it will work exactly as expected.  I'm marking answered, but also going mention that our alternative solution was supply negative integer values to the new entities so they are unique while in-memory/before saving the context, but get the identity values assigned correctly when saving to the database...

Answer (score 0):

Your mock repository could retrieve the id from an id generator (simple counter), that increments with each consecutive call.

Comment: Do you basically mean I should define a globally-scoped counter and add a callback to the AddObject() for my FakeObjectSet that increments the counter and assigns its new value to the current entity being inserted?

Comment: Turns out we are mocking the ObjectContext, but are using a concrete instance of FakeObjectSet<T>.  That means we cannot mock or add a callback to the AddObject method on an instance of FakeObjectSet<Foo> or whatever...

Comment: Not sure if your model will allow it but is it not possible to use GUID's as your key. That way it will always be unique and won't have any problems inserting and retrieving.  However I presume as you are inserting 0 at the moment you are inserting ints but thought I would suggest it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I should stub the return values from the database and so on I will by myself decide what primary keys each object will have.

What is your goal for the tests?